# Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( 1-\frac{1}{n^2+1}\right)^{n^3}$ is convergent or divergent.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( 1-\frac{1}{n^2+1}\right)^{n^3}.$$ How can I prove the convergence or divergence of it?

I tried to use the comparison test and claim that:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( 1-\frac{1}{n^2+1}\right)^{n^3}\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( 1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{n^2}$$ but the right series divergent because the limit of the sequence is e and therefore the series is divergent.

Comment: How about proving $$\left( 1-\frac{1}{(n^2+1)}\right)^{n^3} \sim e^{-n}$$

Comment: Try using the Root Test.

Comment: and then the series will be convergent? how can you prove this?

Comment: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcii/roottest.aspx

Comment: I know what the root test is, I don't know how it helps me to solve this. If I use the root test here assuming that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}( 1-\frac{1}{(n^2+1)})^{n^3} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}( 1-\frac{1}{(n^2+1)})^{n}$ and then using the root test on the right side, I will get 1, which is inconclusive with the root test.

Comment: @Somuser just apply the root test directly, which would give $(1 - 1/(1+n^2))^{n^2}$ which converges to $e^{-1} < 1$.

Comment: Reading your title literally, a series can either be convergent or divergent but not both and it can't be neither. Hence proved :)

Comment: @Somuser Please let me know how to improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer you can. And feel free to up vote and accept an answer as you see fit.

Answer (score 4):

Using $\log(1+x)\le x$ for $x\ge -1$, we have for $n\ge 1$

$$\begin{align}\left(1-\frac1{n^2+1}\right)^{n^3}&=e^{n^3 \log\left(1-\frac1{n^2+1}\right)}\\\\
&\le e^{-n^3/(n^2+1)}\\\\
&\le e^{-n/2}
\end{align}$$

And you can conclude now.

Comment: thank you very much. is there anyway to solve this without using the equality $e^{log(x)}=x$?

Comment: @Somuser That equality is elementary from high school: it follows at once from the very definition of the logarithm and exponential functions ...

Comment: I know this equality but I wouldn't think to use this "trick" I would keep trying using the convergence tests

Comment: @Somuser Sure.  Note that $\left(1+\frac1{n^2+1}\right)^{n^3}=\frac1{\left(1+\frac1{n^2}\right)^{n^3}}$.  From Taylor's theorem $\left(1+\frac1{n^2}\right)^{n^3}=1+n+O(n^2)$.  and now you can compare to the series with general terms $\frac1{n^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use the inequality
$$
1-t\le e^{-t}.
$$
Now you can compare your series to the series
$$
\sum \exp\left(-\frac{n^3}{n^2+1}\right)
$$
which in turn can be compared to the series
$$
\sum e^{-cn}
$$
for an appropriate constant $c>0$.

Comment: Looks similar to mine

Comment: Yep, my $1-t\le e^{-t}$ is analogous to your $\log(1+x)\le x$.

Answer (score 1):

Render

$(1-\frac{1}{n^2+1})^{n^3}=(\frac{n^2}{n^2+1})^{n^3}=(1+\frac{1}{n^2})^{-n^3}$ (**)

Then as $n\to\infty, (1+\frac{1}{n^2})^{-n^\color{blue}{2}}\to1/e$, so the terms of the series $\in O(2^{-n})$.  Therefore convergence by comparison with a geometric series.

(**)  You may have missed the minus sign in the exponent when you set up your comparison test.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
$$
\left( 1-\frac{1}{(n^2+1)}\right)^{n^3}= \frac{1}{\left( 1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{n^3}}
$$

Now, for $n \geq 2$ you have
$$
\left( 1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{n^3} \geq \binom{n^3}{2}(\frac{1}{n^2})^2=\frac{n^3-1}{2n}
$$

Therefore
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( 1-\frac{1}{(n^2+1)}\right)^{n^3} \leq \frac{1}{2}+\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{2n}{n^3-1}
$$

It is trivial to show that the sum on the RHS is convergent.

Comment: Your first line is wrong. It should be $\left( 1-\frac{1}{(n^2+1)}\right)^{n^3}= \frac{1}{\left( 1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{n^3}}$.

Comment: @TonyK Thank you fixed it. I replaced $n^2+1$ by $(n+1)^2$.